# C# file is null, crashes when making an instance.

Tags: c#

This is my settings.cs class:

```
    public class Settings
    {
        static FileIniDataParser _parser = new FileIniDataParser();
        IniData _data = _parser.ReadFile("Config.ini");
        public int GetInt(string section, string key)
        {
            string keyValue = _data[section][key];
            int setting = int.Parse(keyValue);
            return setting;
        }
}
```

This will crash if Config.ini doesn't exist because it tries to read from a file that doesn't exist. But in order for me to make the file I first have to make an instance of the object. But when making the instance it crashes.

I can always do this to make it work, but if I do that I have to repeat my self when making GetBool

```
        public int GetInt(string section, string key)
    {
        FileIniDataParser _parser = new FileIniDataParser();
        IniData _data = _parser.ReadFile("Config.ini");
        string keyValue = _data[section][key];
        int setting = int.Parse(keyValue);
        return setting;
    }
```

And repeating your self is never good.

Comment: @HimBromBeere It compiles just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check if the file exists before reading it and put everything in the definition of the `_data` field in the default constructor of the `Settings` class:

```
public class Settings
{
        static FileIniDataParser _parser = new FileIniDataParser();
        IniData _data;
        public Settings()
        {
            if (!File.Exists("Config.ini"))
            {
              // create the config file 
            }

            _data = _parser.ReadFile("Config.ini");
        }

        public int GetInt(string section, string key)
        {
            string keyValue = _data[section][key];
            int setting = int.Parse(keyValue);
            return setting;
        }
}
```

Comment: I did try something like this but I were not aware of the File keyword. Thanks.

Comment: @foobar it's in the `System.IO` namespace. You may also want to use a 'real' filepath instead of just the filename. If you want to load a file that is in the same folder as your executable, you could use `Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectory(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Config.ini");`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Steffens answer which provides the "how to solve" here is the "why to do so".

Generally you should never create instances that cannot be used. Creating an instance of `Setting` that excplicitely needs a file where the file does not exist should ALLWAYS throw an exeption. Using any methods on such an instances makes no sense at all as ALL of them will fail.

So check if the file exists (see Steffens answer on how to) within the ctor and if not throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Use a FactoryMethod, initialising an object using IO in a (static) constructor is always a bad idea.

```
public class Settings
    {
        private readonly IniData _data;

        private Settings(IniData data){
            _data = data;
        }

        public static Settings InitFrom(string fname){
           var _parser = new FileIniDataParser();
           var data = _parser.ReadFile(fname);
           return new Settings(data);
        }

        public int GetInt(string section, string key)
        {
            string keyValue = _data[section][key];
            int setting = int.Parse(keyValue);
            return setting;
        }
}
```

Now you can create the Settings in a controlled way:

```
try{
   var settings = Settings.InitFrom("Config.ini");
}
catch(IOException iox){
    //something useful
}
var x = settings.GetInt("section","key");
```

And you make the clear that initialisation is more expensive then just a new {}